# PHP MySQLi prepared statement fetch - first row empty?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

The following code:

```
        $con = ConnectDB::getConnection();
    if ($stmt = $con->prepare('---SQL here with 1 param---')) {
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $this->id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($device_id, $device_identifier);

        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $device = new Device($device_identifier, $device_id);
            $all_devices[] = $device;
        }
```

fetches an empty result? The first time through the loop, the $device_id and $device_identifier is empty, but the fetch() method returns true so it runs. HOWEVER - the SECOND iteration actually contains my result.

I could simply check if they are empty and ignore them, but i really can't understand why it is returning an empty pair? I tried running the SQL directly on the DB and it just returns 1 result row?

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have defined `$all_devices = array();`?

Answer (score 0):

As you may imagine, MySQLi prepared statement fetch does not return an empty first row. As such a behavior would make a very little sense.

You need to learn to create a *correct* proof for your assertions.
The code you posted is incorrect one. For some reason you are trying to judge a matter by indirect consequences. **Why not to examine the matter itself?**

```
    $con = ConnectDB::getConnection();
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('---SQL here with 1 param---')) {
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $this->id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($device_id, $device_identifier);

    $stmt->fetch();
    var_dump($device_identifier, $device_id);
```

-- this code will tell you unambiguously, if your assumption on empty result was right or wrong.

After learning that, you may start *debugging*, to find a spot in *your own code* that is responsible for the current behavior.

Hope it helps.